# Cannot get Powershell GUI to modify variable

Tags: powershell, user-interface, variables

I'm creating a GUI to enter in data then store into some variables to work with later. The problem I'm having is modifying the variables once the user clicks the OK button. I have the following code:

```
$button4 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button4.Text = "button"
$button4.Width = 60
$button4.Height = 30
$button4.Add_Click({
    $variable = "test"
})
```

$variable gets assigned with the Add_Click function but I'm not able to access it anywhere else. This makes sense as I read about Powershell scopes. But how am I supposed to access the information I set in there? I'm using [this Microsoft guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx) as to build the GUI. In their example I should be able to return $x at the end of the script. But when I do it the variable isn't available.

Comment: Try declaring the variable outside of the script block `( {} )`.  e.g. `[String]$variable; $but..`

Comment: Just tried putting `[String]$variable` above the the block of code and I get the same result. I also tried creating a function at the start of the script that the Add_Click part calls and it's not handing it off to it. So I know have:
`function writemessage($input) {
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

$wshell.Popup($input,0,"Done",0x1)

}

$button4 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button4.Text = "button"
$button4.Width = 60
$button4.Height = 30
$button4.Add_Click({
    $variable = "test"
    writemessage $variable

})`

Comment: That didn't work well. I put the code here: https://pastebin.com/C5pjrSdN

Comment: try `$script:variable = "test"` to avoid scope issues. Also, don't use `$input` as that is an automatic variable and may not behave like you would expect. Lastly, I would strongly suggest using [FoxDeploy's guid to making a GUI](https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/), even if it means having to start over.

Comment: Aha! So `$script:variable = "test"` would work for a single run but then error out until I cleared the variables. However changing $input to something else fixed the issue. Thanks so much!